# Pentagram using css

Tags: html, css, drawing

can anyone tell me how to draw pentagram such as this using CSS?
10 straight lines I need to treat each of them separately (different color, thickness etc.)
Thank you in advance
[image]

Comment: I think you can find this useful: https://codepen.io/Levi/pen/fKFjL and http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/dVp6p/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#pentagram {margin: 250px auto;}
#pentagram div {
  position:absolute;height:5px;border-radius:2px;
}

#star_1{transform:rotate(180deg) translateY(77px);background:#bb0000;width:476px;}
#star_2{transform:rotate(-36deg) translateY(77px);background:#bb0000;width:476px;}
#star_3{transform:rotate(36deg) translateY(77px);background:#bb0000;width:476px;}
#star_4{transform:rotate(108deg) translateY(77px);background:#bb0000;width:476px;}
#star_5{transform:rotate(-108deg) translateY(77px);background:#bb0000;width:476px;}

#out_1{transform:rotate(180deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;}
#out_2{transform:rotate(-36deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;}
#out_3{transform:rotate(36deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;}
#out_4{transform:rotate(108deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;}
#out_5{transform:rotate(-108deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;}
```

```html
<div id="pentagram">
  <div id="star_1"></div>
  <div id="star_2"></div>
  <div id="star_3"></div>
  <div id="star_4"></div>
  <div id="star_5"></div>

  <div id="out_1"></div>
  <div id="out_2"></div>
  <div id="out_3"></div>
  <div id="out_4"></div>
  <div id="out_5"></div>
</div>
```

i thik it's better use translate than "top and left" to place your lines

Edit:

```
#pentagram div {
  height:5px;border-radius:2px;
}
```

represents the common css flags for all branches, if you want custom widthfor the branches, just cut and paste it into the corresponding IDs

```
#out_3{transform:rotate(36deg) translateY(-202px);background:#00bb00;width:296px;margin-left:90px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;}
```

Comment: An additional question, what if I want one of the lines dotted? As there a css atribut for that? Thank you

Comment: yeah, just check https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp, but make sure youre using borders, and not background for that (like my code)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pentagram{margin:0 auto;margin-top:45px;margin-bottom:75px;height:500px;width:500px;border-radius:500px;border:5px solid #bb0000;position:relative;}#pentagram div{position:absolute;background:#bb0000;width:476px;height:5px;}
#star_1{top:328px;left:12px;}
#star_2{top:183px;left:-38px;transform:rotate(-37deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-37deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-37deg);}
#star_3{top:183px;right:-38px;transform:rotate(37deg);-ms-transform:rotate(37deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(37deg);}
#star_4{top:268px;right:-60px;width:480px !important;transform:rotate(107deg);-ms-transform:rotate(107deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(107deg);}
#star_5{top:268px;left:-60px;width:480px !important;transform:rotate(-107deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-107deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-107deg);}
```

```html
<div id="pentagram">
<div id="star_1"></div>
<div id="star_2"></div>
<div id="star_3"></div>
<div id="star_4"></div>
<div id="star_5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that solution however I need to have straight lines even on top (not a circle) per picture and I need to be able to change the colors of each 10 lines.